# Facebook share and post with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to have Facebook posting and sharing from my ionic app. i have got one sample that you can post but it contains only text. i need to enhance it to image and links as well. please if someone can help me in this.

sample code can be found here.

http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/sociogram-angularjs-ionic-facebook/

Comment: It's best if you paste your sample code into the question in case the link disappears in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{YOUR URL}}, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

and

```
window.open('https://www.twitter.com/share?url={{YOUR URL}}, '_system', 'location=yes');
```